# The probability that the problem is solved correctly by at least one of them

Tags: probability

Question: Four persons independently solve a certain problem correctly with probabilities 1/2, 3/4, 1/4 and 1/8.Then the probability that the problem is solved correctly by at least one
of them is ?

Solution:

say P(A)=1/2, P(B)=3/4, P(C)=1/4, P(D)=1/8

and P(A')=1 -1/2 = 1/2, P(B')= 1 - 3/4 = 1/4, P(C') = 1 - 1/4 = 3/1, P(D') = 1 - 1/8 = 7/8

Probability(at least one of them solves correctly) = 1-  Probability(None of them solves correctly)

Probability(None of them solves correctly) = P(A').P(B').P(C').P(B') = 1/2 * 1/4 * 3/4 * 7/8 = 21/256

P(at least one of them solves correctly) = 1 - 21/256 = 235/256. This is the complimentary method and it's the correct answer.

But when I try to do the direct method i.e

Required probability = (Number of ways at least one solved)/(Total number of ways all solved)

Number of ways at least one solved =  [P(A).P(B').P(C').P(D') ] + [P(A').P(B).P(C').P(D')] + [P(A').P(B').P(C).P(D')] + [ (P(A').P(B').P(C').P(D)]

= [1/2 * 1/4 * 3/4 * 7/8] + [1/2 * 3/4 * 3/4 * 7/8} + [1/2 * 1/4 * 1/4 * 7/8] + [1/2 * 1/4 * 3/4 * 1/8]

= 21/256 + 63/256 + 7/256 + 3/256

= 94/256

Total number of ways all solved = P(A) * P(B) * P(C) 8 P(D)

= 1/2 * 3/4 * 1/4 * 1/8 = 3/256

Required probability = (Number of ways at least one solved)/(Total number of ways all solved)

= $\frac{\frac{94}{256}}{\frac{3}{256}}$ = $\frac{94}{3}$

I know the probability shouldn't be greater than 1. Where am I doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: In the second method you are calculating the probability that exactly one of them answers correctly. But you want the probability that at least one solves it correctly. So if you want to do it that way, you should add the probability that exactly 1 answers correctly + probability exactly two answer correctly, etc, and you should arrive to the same result. However, this is more tedious, so I would suggest using only the first method.

Comment: You should use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) not only when you type fractions, but when you type **any** mathematical formula. $P(A)$ is a formula, so you type $\text{\$P(A)\$}$, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> Number of ways at least one solved = [P(A).P(B').P(C').P(D') ] + [P(A').P(B).P(C').P(D')] + [P(A').P(B').P(C).P(D')] + [ (P(A').P(B').P(C').P(D)]

If you add *probabilities* you can’t get the *number of ways*. The probability is a real number in $[0,1]$, the number if ways is a non-negative integer.

What you found here is the probability that **exactly** one person solved the problem, not **at least** one.

> Total number of ways all solved = P(A) * P(B) * P(C) * P(D)

This is the probability that everyone solved the problem. It happens rarely, this is nowhere near **total** something.

You first reasoning is correct. Just use that.

If you want to use the “direct” reasoning, you should add probabilities that exactly one person solved the problem (which you found), probabilities that exactly two persons solved the problem ($\binom42=6$ more summands), probabilities that exactly three persons solved the problem ($\binom43=4$ more summands), and finally the probability of everyone solving the problem (which you also found). Look at how tedious the “direct” calculation is:

$$\left(\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac78+
\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac78+
\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac78+
\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac18\right)+$$

$$+\left(\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac18+
\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac18+
\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac78+
\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac18+
\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac78+
\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac78\right)+$$

$$+\left(\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac18+
\frac12 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac18+
\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac18+
\frac12 \cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac78\right)+$$

$$+\frac12\cdot\frac34 \cdot\frac14 \cdot\frac18=$$

$$=\frac{235}{256}.$$